# Netted XML Parsing to fetch attribute values in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-parsing

I am trying to fetch the attributes of a XML which looks like below. I am interested being able to fetch the *name* and the *value* of each list entry as i want to create a logic based on those values.

XML:

```
<object stamp="" type="ObjectList" version="1.0">
    <property name="name" value="abcList" valueType="string"/>
    <property name="description" value="List of" valueType="string"/>
    <property name="objectId" value="abcList" valueType="string"/>
    <property name="branchId" value="e620513e-4c57-431c-999d-77015a307c53" valueType="string"/>
    <property name="elementType" value="Agg" valueType="string"/>
    <property name="list" valueType="table">
        <object type="ObjectList:entry" version="1.0">
            <property name="name" value="Ctrl" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="description" value="I_Ctrl" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="isGenerated" value="false" valueType="boolean"/>
            <property name="objectId" value="83e7326a-8707-4e4e-9c51-0de8b1797542" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="stamp" value="675b2af0-e49d-419a-a7bb-f31eeec91e79_1632162868342" valueType="string"/>
        </object>
        <object type="ObjectList:entry" version="1.0">
            <property name="name" value="red_Balances" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="description" value="ed_Balances" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="isGenerated" value="false" valueType="boolean"/>
            <property name="objectId" value="312f0e0d-92c7-4f0c-ac62-208427e80b05" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="stamp" value="217102c4-7272-4d74-879c-8e6fe17daa96_1632162868504" valueType="string"/>
        </object>
        <object type="ObjectList:entry" version="1.0">
            <property name="name" value="SL" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="description" value="pSL" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="isGenerated" value="false" valueType="boolean"/>
            <property name="objectId" value="d5da8774-d872-4725-bf92-83a6c1677895" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="stamp" value="345c8192-1539-4bcd-abea-408f04eca722_1572226580906" valueType="string"/>
        </object>
        <object type="ObjectList:entry" version="1.0">
            <property name="name" value="ted" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="description" value="ted" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="isGenerated" value="false" valueType="boolean"/>
            <property name="objectId" value="b36f5e2f-8e75-4f11-a85a-c3013a3716db" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="isInvalid" value="true" valueType="boolean"/>
            <property name="stamp" value="7d959075-4936-4a7b-9bd3-e1c1407b68e6_1670018368918" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="Reason" valueType="object">
                <object type="ObjectList:message" version="1.0">
                    <property name="messageEnglish" value="Invalidated" valueType="string"/>
                    <property name="messageLocal" value="Invalidated" valueType="string"/>
                </object>
            </property>
        </object>
    </property>
</object>
```

This XML is fetched from a table with this being one of the rows of that column in that table. I need to check all the rows in that column and be able to get the values of attributes like name, description, isGenerated, objectId, stamp.

Comment: Which language using in Oracle for XML parsing?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL/XQuery. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS and its version.

Answer (score 0):

This will get **name** and **value** for each child **property** of every **ObjectList:entry**. It will exclude any **property** element having a **valueType** of object.

```
SELECT "ObjectListEntryIndex" 
      ,"NameIndex"
      ,"Name"
      ,"Value"
FROM   XMLTABLE('/object/property/object[@type="ObjectList:entry"]/property'
                PASSING XMLTYPE(
'<object stamp="" type="ObjectList" version="1.0">
    <property name="name" value="abcList" valueType="string"/>
    <property name="description" value="List of" valueType="string"/>
    <property name="objectId" value="abcList" valueType="string"/>
    <property name="branchId" value="e620513e-4c57-431c-999d-77015a307c53" valueType="string"/>
    <property name="elementType" value="Agg" valueType="string"/>
    <property name="list" valueType="table">
        <object type="ObjectList:entry" version="1.0">
            <property name="name" value="Ctrl" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="description" value="I_Ctrl" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="isGenerated" value="false" valueType="boolean"/>
            <property name="objectId" value="83e7326a-8707-4e4e-9c51-0de8b1797542" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="stamp" value="675b2af0-e49d-419a-a7bb-f31eeec91e79_1632162868342" valueType="string"/>
        </object>
        <object type="ObjectList:entry" version="1.0">
            <property name="name" value="red_Balances" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="description" value="ed_Balances" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="isGenerated" value="false" valueType="boolean"/>
            <property name="objectId" value="312f0e0d-92c7-4f0c-ac62-208427e80b05" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="stamp" value="217102c4-7272-4d74-879c-8e6fe17daa96_1632162868504" valueType="string"/>
        </object>
        <object type="ObjectList:entry" version="1.0">
            <property name="name" value="SL" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="description" value="pSL" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="isGenerated" value="false" valueType="boolean"/>
            <property name="objectId" value="d5da8774-d872-4725-bf92-83a6c1677895" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="stamp" value="345c8192-1539-4bcd-abea-408f04eca722_1572226580906" valueType="string"/>
        </object>
        <object type="ObjectList:entry" version="1.0">
            <property name="name" value="ted" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="description" value="ted" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="isGenerated" value="false" valueType="boolean"/>
            <property name="objectId" value="b36f5e2f-8e75-4f11-a85a-c3013a3716db" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="isInvalid" value="true" valueType="boolean"/>
            <property name="stamp" value="7d959075-4936-4a7b-9bd3-e1c1407b68e6_1670018368918" valueType="string"/>
            <property name="Reason" valueType="object">
                <object type="ObjectList:message" version="1.0">
                    <property name="messageEnglish" value="Invalidated" valueType="string"/>
                    <property name="messageLocal" value="Invalidated" valueType="string"/>
                </object>
            </property>
        </object>
    </property>
</object>'
)
                COLUMNS "ObjectListEntryIndex" NUMBER PATH 'count(../preceding-sibling::*) + 1'
                       ,"NameIndex" FOR ORDINALITY
                       ,"Name" VARCHAR2(100) PATH '@name'
                       ,"Value" VARCHAR2(100) PATH '@value'
               ) xt
WHERE "ValueType" != 'object'
```

| ObjectListEntryIndex | NameIndex | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | name | Ctrl |
| 1 | 2 | description | I_Ctrl |
| 1 | 3 | isGenerated | false |
| 1 | 4 | objectId | 83e7326a-8707-4e4e-9c51-0de8b1797542 |
| 1 | 5 | stamp | 675b2af0-e49d-419a-a7bb-f31eeec91e79_1632162868342 |
| 2 | 6 | name | red_Balances |
| 2 | 7 | description | ed_Balances |
| 2 | 8 | isGenerated | false |
| 2 | 9 | objectId | 312f0e0d-92c7-4f0c-ac62-208427e80b05 |
| 2 | 10 | stamp | 217102c4-7272-4d74-879c-8e6fe17daa96_1632162868504 |
| 3 | 11 | name | SL |
| 3 | 12 | description | pSL |
| 3 | 13 | isGenerated | false |
| 3 | 14 | objectId | d5da8774-d872-4725-bf92-83a6c1677895 |
| 3 | 15 | stamp | 345c8192-1539-4bcd-abea-408f04eca722_1572226580906 |
| 4 | 16 | name | ted |
| 4 | 17 | description | ted |
| 4 | 18 | isGenerated | false |
| 4 | 19 | objectId | b36f5e2f-8e75-4f11-a85a-c3013a3716db |
| 4 | 20 | isInvalid | true |
| 4 | 21 | stamp | 7d959075-4936-4a7b-9bd3-e1c1407b68e6_1670018368918 |